# Rcpp - can't access elements of StrinvgVector

Tags: r, string, rcpp

http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/working-with-Rcpp-StringVector/

I used the above link to try because I want to work with a string or character vector in R

however Rcpp is for some reason concatenating the elements of the vector I am using Rcout to try to understand what is happening but I have no idea what it is:

```
cppFunction('CharacterVector test(NumericMatrix h, NumericMatrix nt, StringVector d, int r){

            CharacterVector m(h.ncol());
            Function f("paste0");
            for(int i = 0; i < d.size(); i++){
              Rcout << d[i];
            }

            return m;
            }')

h <- matrix(0,nrow=2, ncol =2)
colnames(h) <- c("A", "B")
nt <- matrix(0,nrow=2, ncol =2)

d <- c("2019-03", "2014-04")
test(h, nt, d, 1)
```

the output of Rcout is:

```
2019-032014-04[1] "" ""
```

in stead of:

```
"2019-03" "2014-04"
```

Why is this happening ?

Comment: `Rcout` prints bits to the stdout, in this case the R console. Why would you think it'd automagically put double-quotes around it for you. `Rcout` doens't return values, just prints thingsl

Comment: sry as i am new I didn't understand why they are stuck to each other so I thought they were being concatenated the two pairs of quotation marks after the first output didn't help me at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a space after each element you send to `Rcpp::Rcout`, you have to tell it so. You need to change

```cpp
Rcout << d[i];
```

to

```cpp
Rcout << d[i] << " ";
```

Also, as I now notice thanks to [hrbrmstr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1457051/hrbrmstr)'s comment, you also want quotation marks around each element when they're printed. Again, if you want quotation marks, you have to tell that to `Rcout`, it doesn't happen automatically. Then, you'd further modify the aforementioned line to

```cpp
Rcout << "\"" << d[i] << "\" ";
```

I would also add a new line before the function ends. So, let's compare; I have my C++ code in the file `so-answer.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector test(NumericMatrix h, NumericMatrix nt, StringVector d, int r){

    CharacterVector m(h.ncol());
    Function f("paste0");
    for(int i = 0; i < d.size(); i++){
        Rcout << d[i];
    }

    return m;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector test2(NumericMatrix h, NumericMatrix nt, StringVector d, int r){

    CharacterVector m(h.ncol());
    Function f("paste0");
    for(int i = 0; i < d.size(); i++){
        Rcout << "\"" << d[i] << "\" ";
    }

    Rcout << "\n";

    return m;
}

/*** R
h <- matrix(0,nrow=2, ncol =2)
colnames(h) <- c("A", "B")
nt <- matrix(0,nrow=2, ncol =2)

d <- c("2019-03", "2014-04")
test(h, nt, d, 1)
test2(h, nt, d, 1)
*/
```

Then when I use `Rcpp::sourceCpp()` to compile and expose to R:

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp("so-answer.cpp")
#> 
#> > h <- matrix(0,nrow=2, ncol =2)
#> 
#> > colnames(h) <- c("A", "B")
#> 
#> > nt <- matrix(0,nrow=2, ncol =2)
#> 
#> > d <- c("2019-03", "2014-04")
#> 
#> > test(h, nt, d, 1)
#> 2019-032014-04[1] "" ""
#> 
#> > test2(h, nt, d, 1)
#> "2019-03" "2014-04" 
#> [1] "" ""
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

I'll also note that I'm note sure what all the superfluous code is there for, but I just left it in.